# I'm creating a simple bot, no errors come out during compilation, but the bot doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, telegram-bot

The application.properties is located in the resources folder. It contains the name of the bot and the token that you received when registering the bot via @BotFather in Telegram. Please help me understand where the error might be.

Here is my program code:

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.proj3ct</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringNIRBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringNIRBot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <telegram.version>5.6.0</telegram.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>${telegram.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

BotInitializer

```java
package io.proj3ct.SpringNIRBot.config;

import io.proj3ct.SpringNIRBot.service.TelegramBot;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;

@Component
public class BotInitializer {
    @Autowired
    TelegramBot bot;

    @EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
    public void init() throws TelegramApiException {
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
        }catch (TelegramApiException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

SpringNirBotApplication

```java
package io.proj3ct.SpringNIRBot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringNirBotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringNirBotApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

BotConfig

```java
package io.proj3ct.SpringNIRBot.config;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class BotConfig {

    @Value("${bot.name}")
    String botName;
    @Value("${bot.token}")
    String token;

}
```

TelegramBot

```java
package io.proj3ct.SpringNIRBot.service;

import io.proj3ct.SpringNIRBot.config.BotConfig;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

@Setter
@Getter
@Component
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    final BotConfig config;


    public TelegramBot(BotConfig config) {
        super();
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return config.getBotName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken () {
        return config.getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        if(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chartId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            switch (messageText) {
                case "/start":
                    startCommandReceived(chartId, update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
                    break;
                default: sendMessage(chartId, "Sorry, command was not recognized");
            }
        }

    }

    private void startCommandReceived(long chartId, String name) {
        String answer = "Hi, " + name + ",nice to meet you!";
        sendMessage(chartId, answer);
    }

    private void sendMessage (long chartId, String textToSend) {
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.setChatId(String.valueOf(chartId));
        message.setText(textToSend);

        try {
            execute(message);
        }catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that the bot would write a welcome letter to the /start command, but nothing happens.

Comment: is bot connected to the room ? and did you try to print some log on **onUpdateReceived** that can prove if it is really receiving any message.